# Invalid syntax on an empty line

Tags: python

For some reason, I'm getting an error:

```
File "prode.py", line 50

                                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is what my code looks like:

```
def start():
#Is the user trying to get pixel or percentage data,
if (len(sys.argv)) == 4:
    if (sys.argv[1]) == "-px":
        pct = float(sys.argv[2])
        pxl = float(sys.argv[3])
        divByCent = pct*pxl
        ans = divByCent/100
        print "%f pct of %f px = %f px" % (pct, pxl, ans)
    elif (sys.argv[1]) == "-pe":
        pxlOne = float(sys.argv[2])
        pxlTwo = float(sys.argv[3])
        divByTwo = pxlOne * 100
        ans = divByTwo / 1280
        print "%f pxl of %f pxl = %f pct" % (pxlOne, pxlTwo, ans)
#Or something based on a ratio?
elif (len(sys.argv) == 3):
    if (sys.argv[1] == "-use"): ratioCalc = Ratio(float(sys.argv[2]), float(sys.argv[3])

    #Line 50
```

Does anybody know where this is coming from?

Comment: The end of your last non-empty line is missing a closed parenthesis.

Comment: No idea why this is a closed question, this helped me diagnose an error that was driving me mad

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've missed last parenthesis:

`if (sys.argv[1] == "-use"): ratioCalc = Ratio(float(sys.argv[2]), float(sys.argv[3]))`

Comment: This is crazy, especially because the error line output can be anywhere after the missed paranthesis. Ofc an IDE would tell you this, but if you stuck without one, this is a very annoying error.